# Translating "I want to go back to..."

Tags: traducción, gramática

Picture this: A couple has a bad break up and both parties go their own separate ways. Years pass and one fine day, they run into each other. Memories come flooding and emotions go high. The girl, wanting to re-start their relationship, tells the guy, "*I want to go back to where we were before.*"

How would one say what the girl said, in Spanish? Is the following translation correct?

> **Quiero continuar dónde estábamos antes.**

Would **volver** suit this context better than **continuar**?

Is there a more natural way to say the same thing?

Sorry for the long story but I had to give some context. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, don't worry for giving context. It is actually really helpful for giving more accurate and meaningful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are acceptable, but have slightly different meanings (as in English). Some alternatives:

> *Quiero volver a donde estábamos ante*s (slightly weird construction,
>   but natural)
>
> *Quiero volver a donde estábamos entonces.*
>
> *Quiero continuar/retomar/recomenzar nuestra relación tal como era entonces.*

In all cases, "quiero" (I want) would probably be replaced by the more tentative "quisiera" (I'd wish).

Comment: I would change "recomezar", that has the inflection of "start anew" and add "recuperar". apart form that great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative and more natural way in Spain:
Quiero volver donde lo dejamos

Comment: ¿No sería incluso mejor *Quiero volver a donde lo dejamos*?  *Volver* normalmente no es transitivo en este caso, por ejemplo, sería difícil decir *Quiero volver España* en vez de *Quiero volver **a** España*

Comment: Sería perfecto. :)